# Thue equation $ x^4 - 6 x^3 y - x^2 y^2 + 6 x y^3 - y^4=-1 $

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I need help solving the Thue equation
$ x^4 - 6 x^3 y - x^2 y^2 + 6 x y^3 - y^4=-1 $.
It can be written as
$ x(x-y)(x+y)(x-6y) = (y-1)(y+1)( y^2 +1) $. 
From this I found 8 solutions (0,1),(0,-1),(1,1),(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,-1),(6,1) and (-6,-1). But there are two more solutions (15,17) and (-15,-17), and I don't know how to get them.
I would be grateful for any kind of suggestions.

Comment: How did you get these $8$ solutions?

Comment: If $ x=0 $ than $ 0=(y−1)(y+1)(y^2+1) $, so $ y=1 $ or $ y=-1 $, hence (0,1) and (0,-1). If $ x-y=0 $, $ x=y $ than $ 0=(y−1)(y+1)(y^2+1) $, so $ y=1 $ or $ y=-1 $, hence (1,1) and (-1,-1). etc

Comment: *But there are two more solutions* - No, there aren't. $($At least not below $10^3)$.

Comment: You can try to put solution (15, 17) instead (x, y) into the equation, and you will see that's a solution as well.

Comment: In Pari/GP (which is freely available and documented) you can type : thue(thueinit(x^4-6*x^3-x^2+6*x-1),-1) to get a reply of [[-1, 1], [1, -1], [0, 1], [0, -1], [1, 1], [-1, -1], [15, 17], [-15, -17], [6, 1], [-6, -1]]. This "proves" that the solutions are as listed. The Thue solver here depends upon lower bounds for linear forms in (complex) logarithms and lattice basis reduction (facts which may or may not interest you).

Comment: I used Pari/GP, that's how I know there are two more solutions. But I don't know how to get to them on my own.

Answer (score 1):

OP seems to be looking for a simple method that would ensure an easy discovery of all solutions listed. One such simple method is to let $y$ run through $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3, ...$ and calculate $(y−1)(y+1)(y^2+1) = y^4-1$. From the left hand side, we can see that $x$ must be a divisor of $y^4-1$ and we simply check all divisors of $y^4-1$. For $ y = \pm 17$ we get that $y^4-1 = 83520$ which is divisible by $15$.

Comment: Right. Nice idea, thanks. :)